# Сравнение данных с вводом в R и Python

Tags: python, r, конвертация

Доброго времени суток. Учу python ну и собственно хочу перевести код с R и очень интересует следующий вопрос: Как удобнее всего было бы реализовать сравнение данных из таблицы excel с критериями, которые вводятся в скрипте, как это сделано в скрипте R?

```
    a <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Введите количество рабочих на вашем предприятии: 1, если меньше 8,5 тыс.чел, 2 в противном случае: "))
    b<-as.numeric(readline(prompt="Введите тип вашей индустрии: 2, если высокодоходная, 1 в противном случае: "))
    c<-as.numeric(readline(prompt="Введите производительность труда вашего предприятия в тыс. руб./чел: "))
    d<-as.numeric(readline(prompt="Введите рентабельность компании в %: "))
    e<-as.numeric(readline(prompt="Введите темп роста компании в %: "))
    tryCatch(
      { localenv <- environment()
      asde<-work_file[as.numeric(work_file$WORKER)==a & as.numeric(work_file$OTRASL)==b & (work_file$PROISVOD>c-500 & work_file$PROISVOD<c+500) & (work_file$RENTAB>d/100-0.2 & work_file$RENTAB<d/100+0.2) & (work_file$TEMP>e/100-0.3 & work_file$TEMP<e/100+0.3),]
      xyz <- asde[,c("КОМП", "REAL")]
      saq<-ggplot(xyz, aes(x = factor(xyz[,1]), y = xyz[,2], fill=xyz[,1]),environment = localenv) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") + xlab("Название компаний") + 
        ylab("Объем реализации в млн. рублей")+ ggtitle("Данные по схожим компаниям") + theme(text = element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
                                                                                              axis.text.x = element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
                                                                                              axis.text.y = element_text(size=14,face="bold")) + 
        scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0, max(xyz[,2])+7000), breaks = seq(0, max(xyz[,2]), by = 10000)) +
        geom_text(aes(label = xyz[,2]), size = 5,face="bold",vjust=0)
      return(list(saq,asde))
      },
      error=function(cond) {
        print(paste("Компаний с похожими данными не выявлено. Проверьте правильность ввода данных или воспользуйтесь опцией прогнозирования"))
      },
      warning=function(cond) {
        print(paste("Компаний с похожими данными не выявлено. Проверьте правильность ввода данных или воспользуйтесь опцией прогнозирования"))
      })
  }
```

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Как прочитать данные из Excel-файла? Они разные бывают - нужно указать формат.

Comment: Это достаточно легко делается на Pandas и вам возможно уже знакома работа с DataFrame'с из R. Если вы выложите пример data set'а (в виде текста или ссылки на CSV/Excel/TSV file), краткое описание того что нужно сделать и пример результирующего DataFrame (data set), то я мог бы набросать рабочий вариант на Python + Pandas... PS построение графиков на Pandas делается тоже очень легко

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nb1xfw5be5kqpzn/data.xlsx?dl=0 < ссылка на данные, нужно провести: 1. Анализ компаний с сопоставимыми характеристиками, 2. Построение прогноза для объема реализации компании. В первом случае, (та часть скрипта, которая указана выше) проводится сравнение между базой и данными, которые вводит пользователь по:

Comment: 1. Находятся в такой же отрасли, что и компания, с введенными данными (высоко/низко доходная)
2. Имеют такое же количество рабочих (больше 8,5 тыс. чел или меньше)
3. Имеют примерно такую же производительность труда (с разрешенным отклонением в 500 тыс.руб./чел)
4. Рентабельность у данных компаний также должна находится на одном уровне в введенными данными (допускается отклонение в 20%)
5. Темп роста составляет плюс/минус 30%, что у введенной компании

Comment: Это всё находится в строке:                                                               asde<-work_file[as.numeric(work_file$WORKER)==a & as.numeric(work_file$OTRASL)==b & (work_file$PROISVOD>c-500 & work_file$PROISVOD<c+500) & (work_file$RENTAB>d/100-0.2 & work_file$RENTAB<d/100+0.2) & (work_file$TEMP>e/100-0.3 & work_file$TEMP<e/100+0.3),]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начать можно с такого варианта:

```
import pandas as pd

url = r'd:/download/data.xlsx'

# читаем Excel в Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(url)

# это нужно будет переделать на ввод текста
# или можно читать это из другого CSV/Excel файла
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1000
d = 50
e = 80

# query ...
qry = '''
WORKER == @a & \
OTRASL == @b & \
PROISVOD > @c-500 & PROISVOD < @c+500 & \
RENTAB > @d/100-0.2 & RENTAB < @d/100+0.2 & \
TEMP > @e/100-0.3 & TEMP < @e/100+0.3 \
'''

print(df.query(qry))
```

Output:

```
         КОМП  НОМЕР      REAL   TEMP  RENTAB  PROISVOD  OTRASL  WORKER
25   Башнефть     18   36948.0  0.833   0.329     838.1       1       1
112  Норильск      6  134617.0  0.878   0.394    1402.1       1       1
```

Comment: О, отлично. Я в принципе похожее написал. У меня в догонку еще такой вопрос по поводу регрессии: m<-lm(data=work_file, log(REAL)~RENTAB+OTRASL+WORKER+log(PROISVOD)), как и каким пакетом её лучше представить?

Comment: @PawełDiulin, я R не знаю, поэтому перевести эту строку не смогу. По поводу пакетов - советую посмотреть на [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) (полное название: `sci-kit learn`)

Comment: @PawełDiulin, еще стоит посмотреть на [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) пакет

Comment: @PawełDiulin, меня "зацепила" ваша задача и я решил немного (хотя бы поверхностно) разобраться в теме `machine learning`. Вы можете пояснить вашу цель? Это предсказание `REAL` в зависимости от `['RENTAB','OTRASL','WORKER','PROISVOD']` или визуализация или что-то еще? И почему вы выбрали именно эту формулу: log(REAL)~RENTAB+OTRASL+WORKER+log(PROISVOD)?

Comment: Да, предсказание значения + доверительные границы для прогноза.   Формула чисто из эконометрических соображений, чтобы не было гетероскедастичности.

Comment: @PawełDiulin, сейчас попробую набросать предсказание на `sklearn`... Жалко, что у вас так мало данных - предсказание будет не очень точным...

Comment: @PawełDiulin, попробовал разные методы: `LinearRegression, RandomForestRegressor, SM.OLS, SVR, KernelRidge` - все дают очень плохие предсказания. Проблема в недостаточно большом объеме данных - их по-моему не хватает для "тренировки" модели. PS пробовал обе формулы: ` log(REAL)~RENTAB+OTRASL+WORKER+log(PROISVOD)` и ` REAL~RENTAB+OTRASL+WORKER+PROISVOD`. Я так и не понял как можно предсказать _REAL_ при формуле `log(REAL) ~ ...` или вы сравниваете значение логарифма и значение `REAL` вас не интересует?